# How to deal with a REST API structures redundancy?

Tags: rest

I am currently build a REST API for a webservice that, amongst other things, handles user bans.

The current API I designed look like:

---

URL: `GET /user/<user_id>/bans/<session_id>`

Description: Get the ban on the specified session for the specified user.

Output:

```
{
  session_id: 1,
  banned_until: "..."
}
```

---

URL: `GET /user/<user_id>/bans`

Description: Get all bans for the specified user.

Output:

```
[
  {
    session_id: 1,
    banned_until: "..."
  },
  {
    session_id: 2,
    banned_until: "..."
  }
]
```

---

URL: `PUT /user/<user_id>/bans/<session_id>`

Description: Set or update a ban on the specified session for the specified user.

Input:

```
{
  session_id: 1,
  banned_until: "..."
}
```

Output:

```
{
  session_id: 1,
  banned_until: "..."
}
```

---

Now one of my coworkers believes that the API is wrong because, for instance in the case of the `PUT`, the user has to specify the `session_id` twice: once in the URL and once in the content and those two have to match (which means an extra check server-side). He makes the same comment for the `GET` where the user specifies the session id in the URL to get it back in the response, meaning a waste of bandwidth.

While I understand his concerns, I however think the current design as it is, is simpler for the user (only one data structure to care about) and that the extra check on the server isn't that much work to do compared to the comfort it brings the user.

Is there an official guideline regarding this in the REST best-practices ? What is the usual/recommended way of dealing with this ?

Comment: In general I'd rather transmit a session ID in a cookie.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer These are not web sessions, but game sessions that have nothing to do with the browser issuing the request.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think what you are talking about is the different between the `PUT` and `POST` methods.

From the [RESTful CookBook](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/):

> Use PUT when you can update a resource completely through a specific resource. For instance, if you know that an article resides at http://example.org/article/1234, you can PUT a new resource representation of this article directly through a PUT on this URL.

So, in the `PUT` example you gave, I think it is perfectly valid to specify the sessionID in the URL since you are storing the ban at a specific point.

However you could also create a `POST` service at `URL: POST /user/<user_id>/bans` to satisfy your co-worker. :-)